# How to Put an Event Listener on Newly Added Forms submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some forms in my webpage with a class name `post_reply`

I am using the following to track the submission of the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".post_reply").submit(function(event){
       // statements
    });
});
```

It works, But If I add some new forms to the page with jquery / javascript, it does not track their submission.

I also tried to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comments").on('submit', 'form.post_reply', function (event) {
      // statements
    });
});
```

In the above `#comments` is the container div. But it also does not work. Any Solution??

Comment: Are you writing these statements within the $(document).ready() functon?

Comment: do you add the event after adding the new form or before...??

Comment: @FreemanLambda Yes I am writing these statements within $(document).ready()

Comment: I faced your same problem just yesterday Rashid. I think event binding occurs only to the existing items in the moment of binding. Elements added later are uneffected by your binding code. Try to put your .on method in a time span that comes soon after your new form elements are born.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying so many ways, finally the following method solved my problem.

```
$("#comments").on('submit', '.post_reply', function (event) {

});
```

Thanks to All For Help.

Answer (score 1):

`.on()` should work. But here's another option:

```
$("body").delegate("form.post_reply", "submit", function() {
  // statements
);
```

But the `.on()` method should really work.

Comment: Am I using .on() Method Correctly?

Comment: @RashidFarooq Or, how about `$("form.post_reply").on("submit", function() {})`? Have you tried it?

Comment: How exactly do you add new forms?